# Console.log(string) doensn't return anything

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I have a problem console logging a string, which I've just put together from an array --why doesn't it print anything in the console when I call "console.log(text2);"?

I can only think it has something to do with the fact that the array indices aren't numbers, but have the same name as the elements --which is because how how I created the array: `a2 [element] = element;`, but I don't know how I can do this differently.

[It looks like this in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky7o0.png)

Javascript code below ---------------------------

```
const text = document.getElementById('textfield');

let a2 = new Array(); 


document.querySelector('form.input-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(text.value);   


    const a1 = text.value.split(' ');
    console.log(a1);


      a1.forEach((element) => {
        function shuffle(element) {
            var arr = element.split('');           // Convert String to array
            
            arr.sort(function() {
              return 0.5 - Math.random();
            });  
            element = arr.join('');                // Convert Array to string
            return element;                        // Return shuffled string
            
          }
    
        element = shuffle(element);
        console.log(element);

       a2 [element] = element; //creates array a2

      });

      
    console.log(a2);
    alert(typeof a2); // returns "object"


    //I want to create a string out of a2 by joining the words back together with ' '

    const text2 = a2.join(' ');
    alert(typeof text2); // returns "string"
  
    console.log(text2); //doesn't return anything





    //lastly I want to output the text back into the html site
    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text2;


});
```

Comment: `a2 [element]` looks like a syntax error?

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong here. For one, use `a2 = [];` rather than `new Array()` (use the primitive syntax), Second, what is `a2 [element] = element` supposed to do? If `a2` is an array, its indices are numbers. Even if `a2` was an object primitive, its indices would be strings, and `a2 [element] = element` would still not work: it would perform type coercion and your element will be "somewhere", but not where you think it is. As such, `element` isn't "in the array", it's "stored as object property, somehow", and `join()` will be a join on an empty array.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that would explain why `join` wouldn't include them in the output. `a = []; a.prop = 'value'; a.join('') // ""`

Comment: (but also: don't use alert, ever. Keep using console.log because it shows you exactly what you tell it to, unlike alert, which doesn't. Also, don't declare `shuffle` inside your foreach, you don't need it redeclared every single iteration. Also, if `element` is a string, don't call it `element`)

Comment: yes, that's what I wrote @evolutionxbox? The _array_ is empty, even if you set object properties.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I commented before the edit btw. I'm also agreeing...

Comment: Tbh i was already confused at the title, `console.log` never returns something.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  `a2 [element] = element` was an attempt at creating a new array from the shuffled elements in the shuffle function. The indices are strings --but they aren't numbered in the array, as you can see from the image. How would you create the array?

Comment: Javascript arrays don't do strings as keys, the array functionality is only defined over numerical indices (the only language that does that is PHP, so if you came from the PHP world: (re)read up on the differences). If you need a dictionary/associative array, use an object literal. That is: `const a2 = {}`. But then you have no functions on the object itself, and if you Need to use `Object`'s utility function, such as `Object.keys(yourobject)` or `Object.values(yourobject)` or even `Object.entries(yourobjct)`. There are many more, but MDN can tell you what those are just fine.

Comment: Although I would strongly recommend hitting up SO's sister site https://codereview.stackexchange.com after fixing your problem so folks can help you turn this into proper JS. There's a lot of code here that shows unfamiliarity with JS, and having some people help explain why what you've written really should be written differently will be of high value to you.

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans -- thank you, I will do that if I ever get this working. I understand some of it, but I'm definitely unfamiliar with js and coding in generel (I've only used arduino to control some motors and read some sensors). This is me trying to complete a project that was given to my class, without a lot of introduction. So I appreciate your help!